# Как удалить в localStorage записи, ключи которых начинается со слова

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Как известно, чтобы взять с localStorage только записи, ключи которых начинается с определённого слова можно использовать код:

```
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var myKey = localStorage.key(i);
    if(myKey.slice(0,6) === 'myWord') {
        console.log(myKey);
    }
}
```

А как удалить все такие записи одновременно? Пробовал так:

```
...
if(myKey.slice(0,6) === 'myWord') {
    localStorage.removeItem(myKey);
}
```

и так:

```
...
if(myKey.slice(0,6) === 'myWord') {
    localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i));
}
```

Но удаляет по одной штуке при каждом запуске кода

А как удалить все сразу при одном запуске?

Comment: `clear` удаляет все записи одновременно

Comment: `clear` удаляет все записи вообще, а мне нужно удалить только те которые начинаются с определённого слова

Comment: тогда только удалять по одному

Comment: Через for in собрать ключи и удалить

Comment: Да, точно, не догадался. Достаточно собрать ключи и удалить в отдельном цикле. Спасибо

Comment: так можно ж сразу удалять, зачем второй цикл?